# How do I write a basic if statement to include code on the index page?

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm so used to writing for Wordpress that I don't know how to do a simple PHP logic statement by itself!

For a very basic project, I'm trying to include an unordered list on the index.php page. Here's an example of code that I am trying to use:

```
        <?php 
        $index = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        if ($index == "/") {
        ?><ul id="links">
            <li><a href="http://facebook.com" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
            <li><a href="example.php">Example</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.php">Test</a></li>
            <li><a href="page.php">Page</a></li>
        </ul>
        <?php } ?>
```

I know this needs to work for index pages ending with the actual URI of index.php as well as a blank suffix without index.php. How can I write this code to work correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`basename()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function to get actual page name like this:

```
    <?php 
    $page = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if ($page == 'index.php' || $page == "/" || $page == '') {
    ?><ul id="links">
        <li><a href="http://facebook.com" class="facebook">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="example.php">Example</a></li>
        <li><a href="test.php">Test</a></li>
        <li><a href="page.php">Page</a></li>
    </ul>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Nice, that works great when the page ends with index.php. It doesn't, however, seem to work correctly with only a trailing slash. I copied and pasted your top PHP code over mine, made the quotations consistent, but am not receiving the correct result with the trailing slash.

Comment: what does $page equal when you var_dump it?

Comment: Hey Mark, I added var_dump below the variable declaration to the PHP code on the index page. It spits back the subdirectory name before the trailing slash (I am in a subdirectory for this project before it goes live). So now I understand why it doesn't show the buttons but I don't know how to fix the problem!

Comment: I guess I will just have to replace "/" with "subdirectory" and that should satisfy this answer. Unless there's a better PHP function with which to do this.

Answer (score 0):

It does work however if you use SCRIPT_NAME with the slashes following.

```
<?php 
    $page = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
    if ($page == 'index.php' || $page == "/" || $page == '') 
    { ?> 
    Hi This should show up.
    <?php }?>
```